# Python structure size dont match

Tags: python, struct

I have some structure which I want to read from binary file. I try to use for python's struct.
Here a string for reading:

```
.... = struct.unpack('I36s36s72sQQIIH4s36s4s20s', datab.read(238))
```

it works fine. I see it by printing values to screen.

Now I want to change "4s" to "I" as it should be. When I change string to:

```
.... = struct.unpack('I36s36s72sQQIIHI36s4s20s', datab.read(238))
```

(change first "4s" to "I"), I getting error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 240
```

As documentation said "I" size is 4 bytes, why my change causes error?

Comment: Maybe a fake prefix or suffix works? (x00)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with alignment. `I` gets aligned on a four-byte boundary, requiring two bytes of padding before it. On the other hand, `4s` has no such requirement.

See [7.3.2.1. Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) for information on how to turn this off.